# RGB values for clear color in iphone?

Tags: iphone

What is RGB and alpha value for clear color?
i want to do it programmatic, don't need [UIColor clearColor]...??

Comment: Why can't you just use `[UIColor clearColor]`, which itself is also programmatic? Why do you want to make life difficult for yourself?

Comment: I think it doesn't have RGB values. Instead it will get the color from its parent and set it.

Comment: coz i want to make more generalize prog.

Answer (score 7):

To represent clear color in rgb format one may use

```
'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

It just includes the alpha value.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW33):

"Returns a color object whose grayscale and alpha values are both 0.0."

Comment: Correct. It doesn't use the RGB colorspace.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a color object whose grayscale and alpha values are both 0.0

```
UIColor *clearColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0/255 alpha:0.0];
```